# Number of likes (acts as votable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to count the number of likes (of pins) by a certain user using the acts as votable gem. I have created a my pins view to show the number of likes and use a statement @pins.likes.size to show the number. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Here is my pins controller

```
      def my_pins
        @pins = current_user.pins
      end

      def like
        @pin.liked_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
      end

      def unlike
        @pin.unliked_by current_user
        redirect_to :back
      end
```

And my view

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-4">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading center">
              <p>Aantal recepten toegevoegd: 
              <b><%= @pins.count %></b></p>
              Aantal favoriete recepten:
              <b><% @pins.likes.size %></b>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added and now it is working :)

```
<%= current_user.find_liked_items.size %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Active record doesn't have a `size` method, try using `count` instead

```
@pins.likes.count
```

Comment: Thanks, however I still get a undefined method `likes' for nil:NilClass error on the count statement. btw, in the documentation they are using size??? https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Comment: ah ok, well please clarify in your question that you are using this gem, because at first I thought is a normal active record model.
As the error says, the problem is that `@pins` is `nil`, check where you're setting it

Comment: Thanks for you response, could you explain how I do that? I am sorry, I am rather new to rails :(